# Изменение URL с добавлением параметров

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, как правильно сделать?
У меня был `url` страницы, который включал в себя 3 параметра, теперь добавился еще один, и я его добавил в `url`.
Раньше было так:

```
RewriteRule ^opisanie/([A-Za-z_0-9]+)/([A-Za-z_0-9]+)/([A-Za-z_0-9]+).html?$ aut_lamp.php?m_lamp_type=$1&m_company_name=$2&m_id_article=$3 [NC,L]
```

А теперь:

```
RewriteRule ^opisanie/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z_0-9]+)/([A-Za-z_0-9]+)/([A-Za-z_0-9]+).html?$ aut_lamp.php?m_id=$1m_lamp_type=$2&m_company_name=$3&m_id_article=$4 [NC,L]
```

Что надо сделать, чтобы уже проиндексированные страницы не потерялись и новые заменили их в поиске?

Comment: люди помогитееееее ))))